# Using Yeppp! on Codeblocks on Windows - setting environment parameters (probably)

Tags: c++, codeblocks, yeppp

I'm trying to get the Yeppp! vector math libraries working on my system (windows 7 with Codeblocks, GNU 4.9.2) in c++ (plain c fails as well). Using the basic 'entropy' example from the website

http://docs.yeppp.info/c/_entropy_8c-example.html

Codeblocks fails to compile and returns

```
Entropy Example.c|| undefined reference to _imp__yepMath_Log_V64f_V64f|

Entropy Example.c|| undefined reference to _imp__yepCore_DotProduct_V64fV64f_S64f|

||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I have added the appropriate linker setting; under 'search directories' I have

```
C:\Program Files(x86) Yeppp! SDK\library\headers
```

I believe it is a problem with the 'status' variable or something not being recognized, likely assert.h.

Edit: So now it is working on Visual Studio. Unfortunately the Yeppp! implementation is much slower than the naive approach by a factor of 4. Turned on /ox and set to use AVX (3630qm).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Code::Blocks uses MinGW GCC as a compiler. Yeppp! provides import libraries for Microsoft Visual Studio (in MS COFF format), which are not compatible with MinGW GCC. To use Yeppp! with MinGW GCC, you should convert the import library (yeppp.lib) into GNU format. The conversion process was [discussed on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/yeppp-discuss/mingw/yeppp-discuss/Z_xmCoOcD78/xe0sgrkR7kYJ).